# Is there a way to programmatically save values to web.config appSettings without destroying comments and formatting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

This code works, but it destroys comments and formatting in Web.config.  Is there a way to write to Web.config that won't destroy formatting?

```
var webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var settings = webConfig.AppSettings.Settings;
settings["Foo"].Value = "Bar";
webConfig.Save();
```

Comment: Why are you programmantically saving to the web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can open the web.config as a standard xml file and use Xpath to locate the node you want to change.

Comment: If OP is going to edit Web.config from host app, it's a bad idea - an indication of bad design. He should choose another place / another way to keep/update data

Comment: However if OP is going to change Web.config from outside - he should use either WCM (his way) or regular XmlDocument (your way)

Comment: You're right. If he really needs to update that setting from the same app they're better options that keep it on web.config.

Comment: Legacy code, 8 years old.  Even though I'm the guy who wrote it 8 years ago.   If I had to do it over again, I would not have used Web.config, so I'm agreeing, and contemplating make a change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio API, load Web.config and call `Format Document` against it